# Laravel with google map is not showing markers from lattitude and longitude values in databse

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, laravel-5

I am trying to show markers on Google map from already stored values (lattitude and longitude) in mysql databse. but when i try to load it markers are not showing in google map. Am new to laravel. please help me to implement it.

Following is the code in view page

```
@extends('user.layout.app')

@section('content')
    <script src="{{ url('js/user/location.js') }}"></script>
    <div class="container-fluid add-location">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <form method="post" action="" name="clinicssview" id="clinicssview" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title"> View Clinics </h4>
                        </div>
                        @if(!empty($errors->all()))
                            <div class="row"> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger"> <span>{{ $error }}</span> </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group hide">
                                                <label class="control-label">Location
                                                    <star>*</star>
                                                </label>
                                                <input id="pac-input" name="location" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">

                                            <!-- <div id="map" height="1000" width="1000"></div> -->

                                            </div>
                                            <h4 >Preview</h4>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div id="regularMap" class="map"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Clinic Name
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="user_name" name="user_name" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="Clinc Name" value="{{$clinics->clinicName}}">
</div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Contact First Name
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="contact_fname" name="contact_fname" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="Contact First Name" value="{{$clinics->clinicFname}}">
                                         </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Contact Second Name
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="contact_sname" name="contact_sname" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="Contact Second Name" value="{{$clinics->clinicLname}}">
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Contact Address
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="contact_address" name="contact_adress" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="Contact Address" value="{{$clinics->clinicAddress}}">
                                         </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Contact City
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="contact_city" name="contact_city" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="City" value="{{$clinics->clinicCity}}">
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Contact State
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="contact_state" name="contact_state" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="State" value="{{$clinics->clinicState}}">
                                       </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Clinic Zip
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="zip" name="zip" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="Zip" value="{{$clinics->clinicZip}}">
                                      </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{$clinics->clinicEmail}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Clinic Phone Number
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="phone" name="phone" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" value="{{$clinics->clinicPhone}}">
                                       </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Clinic Website
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input disabled id="clinic_website" name="clinic_website" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="Website" value="{{$clinics->clinicURL}}">
                                 </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <div class="row">



                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('regularMap'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
@endsection
```

I will get latitude and longitude values by `<?php echo $loc->lat ?> & <?php echo $loc->long ?>` in this same page but i dont know how to pass it, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your script is inside the Laravel blade, you can assign PHP variable longitude and latitude to a javascript variable.

```
//Suppose your PHP variable name is $loc having lat and long attribute
<script>
    let provided_longitude = <?php echo $loc->long; ?>;
    let provided_latitude = <?php echo $loc->lat; ?>;

    console.log(provided_longitude, provided_latitude);
</script>
```

Now you can use provided_longitude and provided_latitude into google map.

[Iframe Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode) inside the example.blade.php

```
<iframe
    width="600"
    height="450"
    frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
    &q={{$loc->lat}},{{$loc->long}}" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

**EDIT 1**

To show the markers from the table (eg: orders having column longitude, latitude)

//Inside Your Controller

```
$orders = Order::select('id', 'longitude', 'latitude');

return view('your.page', [
    'orders' => $orders
]);
```

//Inside your/page.blade.php

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

...

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = <?php echo $orders ?>;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['latitude'], locations[i]['longitude']),
            map: map
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How can i use that, can you please provide me a code

Comment: I am unable to know which Google Map API you are using. I use iframe in my projects to display the location where I can directly send long lat in the query. Added an example above.

Comment: I am using multiple values for lattitude and longitudes

Comment: You need to retrieve from https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml or from the database table?

Comment: Thats what am asking how can i pass it

Comment: Added retrieving from the database

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your database lat long value in marker object in javascript.
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,(Here you have to pass the dynamic value of lat and long which you are getting from the data base)
                label: icon.label
              });

In reference you can go throw the below link.
[how to show marker on map php](http://www.expertphp.in/article/show-marker-on-google-map-using-latitude-and-longitude-with-info-window)